# Create a 3D topographic map using Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, raster

I am currently trying to create an interactive 3D surface plot using plotly in R. My dataset includes a matrix of Latitude and Longitude and I have a DEM for the region I would like to make this surface plot for. However, I am unable to do the same.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Points_new <- data.frame(Points.sp$Long, Points.sp$Lat, Points.sp$Elevation)
Points_new <- as.matrix(Points_new)
p <- plot_ly(z = ~Points_new) %>% add_surface()
p
```

[image]

In the above plot, I manually loaded the elevation values for each of these points, but the problem being that I need these points on a DEM for the region, and everytime I try to load the DEM, I get an error saying - 'z' must be a numeric matrix.

The DEM here is a raster for the region.

Any suggestions? I would ideally want points as small circles on the DEM for the region.